# PHPWord --> How to get header different on first page but footer same on all pages?

Tags: footer, phpword

i use PHP Word to create an invoice form.
I want to have the header on the first page different from subsequent pages but the footer same on all pages.

When i do this:

```
$header_page_1 = $section->addHeader();
$header_page_1->firstPage();
$header_page_1->addImage(
    'myimageurl...',
    array(
    'alignment' => 'right',
            'height'        => 85,
            'marginTop'     => -1,
            'marginLeft'    => -1,
            'wrappingStyle' => 'behind'
    )
);

$header_subseq = $section->addHeader();
$header_subseq->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}', null, array('alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::RIGHT));

$footer_all_pages = $section->addFooter();
$footer_all_pages->addText('Test');
```

i get NO footer at first page

How to setup that the footer is also shown at the first page?
Is the only solution to define the same footer twice like this:

```
$footer_page_1 = $section->addFooter();
$footer_page_1->firstPage();
$footer_page_1->addText('Test');
$footer_subseq = $section->addFooter();
$footer_subseq->firstPage();
$footer_subseq->addText('Test');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the footer section also twice same as header.

One for first page and another for subsequent pages.

```
e.g 
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$footer->firstPage();
$footer->addText(htmlspecialchars('Footer for page'));

$footer_sub = $section->addFooter();
$footer_sub->addText(htmlspecialchars('Footer for page'));
```